# Equality case in Hölder's inequality

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

Let $p$ and $q$ be dual exponents and let $f \in L^p(0,1)$ and $g \in L^q(0,1)$ be non-zero functions. Further assume that $||fg||_1=||f||_p||g||_q$. Show that $f=cg^{q-1}$ where $c$ is constant.

By Hölder we know that $||fg||_1 \leq||f||_p||g||_q$, but I'm not sure how this helps us. By setting $f=cg^{q-1}$ I was able to verify the equality, but I don't know how to prove this is the only solution.

Comment: This result is standard. See the discussion after Theorem 3.5 in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: I looked at Rudin and I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the function are non-negative. Otherwise, the result may not hold, as we can have when $q$ is an even integer $f=1$ and $g=1$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $-1$ on $(1/2,1)$ or even worse $g^{q-1}$ may not be well-defined if $q$ is not rational and $g$ take negative values.

Since $f$ and $g$ are not zero, by scaling, it suffices to consider the case where 
$\left\lVert f\right\rVert_p=\left\lVert q\right\rVert_q=1$.

Observe that for all positive numbers $a$ and $b$, by convexity of the exponential function,
$$
ab=\exp\left(\frac  1p\ln \left(a^p\right)+\frac  1q\ln \left(b^q\right)\right)
\leqslant \frac  1p\exp\left(\ln \left(a^p\right) \right)+
\frac  1q\exp\left(\ln \left(b^q\right) \right)
$$
hence 
$$
\tag{*}
ab\leqslant \frac{a^p}p+\frac{b^q}q, \quad a,b\geqslant 0
$$
and by strict convexity, equality holds if and only if $a^p=b^q$. 
Let 
$$
h:=\frac{f^p}p+\frac{g^q}q-fg.
$$
By $(*)$, $h$ is non-negative and by assumption, $\int h=0$ hence $h=0$ almost everywhere. By the equality case in $(*)$, we derive that $f^p=g^q$ almost everywhere.